# Using CTE and Update in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, common-table-expression

I am converting some SQL Logic from T-SQL used in SSMS to Amazon Redshift. [I believe Redshift is a fork of Postgres version 8.0.2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html) so the below may not be possible unless using Postgres 9.1.

```
WITH CTE_ID AS 
(
SELECT FULL_NAME, COUNT(DISTINCT ID) as ID_COUNT, MAX(ID) AS MAX_ID
FROM MEMBERS
GROUP BY FULL_NAME
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ID) > 1
)
UPDATE a
SET a.ID = b.MAX_ID
FROM MEMBERS a
INNER JOIN CTE_ID b
ON a.FULL_NAME = b.FULL_NAME
```

If this feature is not supported by Amazon Redshift, would my best option be to create a new "temporary" table and populate it with the values the CTE would generate?

Comment: you can turn the  CTE into a derived table `from members join (select ...) as b on ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can re-write the query as a derived table as mentioned by @a_horse_with_no_name:

```
UPDATE MEMBERS
SET a.ID = b.MAX_ID
FROM MEMBERS a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT FULL_NAME, COUNT(DISTINCT ID) as ID_COUNT, MAX(ID) AS MAX_ID
  FROM MEMBERS
  GROUP BY FULL_NAME
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ID) > 1
  ) b
ON a.FULL_NAME = b.FULL_NAME
```

Comment: This is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Existing answers (including the accepted) are invalid. This should work:

```sql
UPDATE members AS a
SET    id = b.max_id
FROM  (
   SELECT full_name, max(id) AS max_id
   FROM   members
   GROUP  BY full_name
   HAVING count(DISTINCT id) > 1
   ) b
WHERE  a.full_name = b.full_name
AND    a.id IS DISTINCT FROM b.max_id;
```

No need for a CTE (though possible). A subquery is simpler.

The target table is only listed once. You'd only repeat it in the `FROM` clause with a (different) alias for special needs.

Target columns in the `SET` list cannot be table-qualified.

Unquoted [names are folded to lower case in Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_names.html). UPPER case spelling only adds confusion.

I added the predicate `AND a.id IS DISTINCT FROM b.max_id` to skip updates on rows that would not change. (Expensive no-op.) You'd only want those in exotic cases to trigger (undeclared) side effects.

More in the [Redshift manual for `UPDATE`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UPDATE.html).

Answer (score 0):

creating a temporary table instead of with clause will work.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE CTE_ID AS
(
SELECT FULL_NAME, COUNT(DISTINCT ID) as ID_COUNT, MAX(ID) AS MAX_ID
FROM MEMBERS
GROUP BY FULL_NAME
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ID) > 1
);

UPDATE a
SET a.ID = b.MAX_ID
FROM MEMBERS a
INNER JOIN CTE_ID b
ON a.FULL_NAME = b.FULL_NAME
```

Comment: The syntax is invalid. And a temporary table would be pointless complication and cost to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd provide an answer that contains a CTE and an update since the current answer with the highest vote rewrote it as an inner join or subquery.

```sql
UPDATE MEMBERS
   SET MEMBERS.ID = b.MAX_ID
  FROM (
      WITH CTE_ID AS (
          SELECT FULL_NAME, 
                 COUNT(DISTINCT ID) as ID_COUNT, 
                 MAX(ID) AS MAX_ID
            FROM MEMBERS
        GROUP BY FULL_NAME
          HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ID) > 1
      )
      SELECT * FROM CTE_ID
    ) b
WHERE MEMBERS.FULL_NAME = b.FULL_NAME
```

Just keep in mind the where has to result in an equi-join (1-to-1).