# Can we use CTE (with clause) for UPDATE query in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'd like to use variable as base date in my Redshift INSET/UPDATE Query, since this base date should be current_date-1 as usual but should be modified flexibly when there is any urgent matter.

I can use variables in WITH clause as follows. I'm just wondering we can do same in Update Query.

```
INSERT INTO SALES (

 TARGET_DATE
,STORE_CODE
,PRODUCT_CODE
,SALES
)

WITH Variables AS (
SELECT 
  CURRENT_DATE-1::DATE   AS VarOpsDate
  --'2021-03-01'::DATE   AS VarOpsDate
),


SALES_CTE AS (
SELECT 
   SALES_DATE
  ,STORE_CODE
  ,PRODUCT_CODE
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN "CATEGORY"='01' THEN SALES ELSE 0 END) AS SALES01
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN "CATEGORY"<>'01' THEN SALES ELSE 0 END) AS SALES02
FROM
  FACT_SALES
WHERE
  SALES_DATE = (SELECT VarOpsDate FROM Variables)
GROUP BY
   SALES_DATE
  ,STORE_CODE
  ,PRODUCT_CODE
)

SELECT
(SELECT VarOpsDate FROM Variables)
,ST.STORE_CODE
,ST.PRODUCT_CODE
,SALES_CTE.SALES01
,SALES_CTE.SALES02
FROM 
    STORE_PRODUCT_LIST ST

LEFT OUTER JOIN
  SALES_CTE
ON
  ST.STORE_CODE = SALES_CTE.STORE_CODE
AND
  ST.PRODUCT_CODE = SALES_CTE.PRODUCT_CODE;
```

If you have any good work-around, please let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: I is covered there, also with workaround examples:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49499233/using-cte-and-update-in-redshift/49499807

Comment: @Edgars T. Many thanks for your advice !! Have a great day :)